# Which domain better for language version?

Tags: seo, domain-registration, multiple-domains, multilingual, internationalization

My company is based in Russia and it's website is `mycompany.ru`.

Now, we are planning to launch German language version and we have option for two domains:

1. `mycompany.de`
2. `germankeyword.ru`

Which one is better regarding the seo point of view? (we will be optimizing the traffic for `germankeyword` phrase).

I understand that the best option would be `germankeyword.de`, but these are already in use.

So, which one would you choose: to have the language in top level domain, or the particular keyword. Will this mismatch affect our Search Engine Rankings?

Answer (score 2):

Google does not allow you to target a site with a country specific TLD to another country.  Matt Cutts recently posted a video about it:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0sCnzzVtNs
As such, you will have a hard time ranking in Germany with a `.ru` domain name.

Furthermore, brands are a much more powerful signal about the quality of a site than keywords these days.  As such, I would choose a branded domain name over a keyword domain name even on a generic TLD such as `.com`.

Go with `mycompany.de`

Comment: Thanks for the video and the explanation. Honestly, I was about to go with the other option :)